# Getting exception while reading element for XML

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I am able to successfully load the XML based property file using below code:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    InputStream is = SampleConfig.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.properties");
    System.out.println(is);
    props.loadFromXML(is);
    String appId = props.getProperty("favoriteSeason");
    System.out.println(appId);
```

My Property File Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<entry key="favoriteSeason">test</entry>
<entry key="favoriteFruit">test1</entry>
<entry key="favoriteDay">test2</entry>
</properties>
```

But however, when I run this I get below exception:

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "properties" must match "(comment?,entry*)".
>       at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.XMLUtils.getLoadingDoc(XMLUtils.java:113)
>       at java.util.XMLUtils.load(XMLUtils.java:85)

Comment: Works for me, output is: 

java.io.BufferedInputStream@3a09a47d
test

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually the problem was with loadFromXML() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use loadFromXML() method to load from a .properties file. I think that is the issue as the stacktrace shows that its not getting the required format of comments-entry type.